# JavaScript Split, Split string by last DOT "."

Tags: javascript, string

JavaScript Split,

1. str = '123.2345.34'  , 
   expected output 123.2345 and 34
2. Str = 123,23.34.23
   expected output 123,23.34 and 23

Goal : JS function to Split a string based on dot(from last) in O(n).
There may be n number of ,.(commas or dots) in string.

Comment: on what basis you are splitting... any logic ?

Comment: dot(.)(last occurrence)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

In order to `split` a string matching only the last character like described you need to use regex "lookahead".

This simple example works for your case:

```js
var array = '123.2345.34'.split(/\.(?=[^\.]+$)/);
console.log(array);
```

Example with destructuring assignment (Ecmascript 2015)

```js
const input = 'jquery.somePlugin.v1.6.3.js';
const [pluginName, fileExtension] = input.split(/\.(?=[^\.]+$)/);
console.log(pluginName, fileExtension);
```

However using either `slice` or `substring` with `lastIndexOf` also works, and albeit less elegant it's much faster:

```js
var input = 'jquery.somePlugin.v1.6.3.js';
var period = input.lastIndexOf('.');
var pluginName = input.substring(0, period);
var fileExtension = input.substring(period + 1);
console.log(pluginName, fileExtension);
```

Comment: Life saver! My old solution was only with split, but that won't take into account various '.' in the file name.

Answer (score 15):

```js
var str = "filename.to.split.pdf"
var arr = str.split(".");      // Split the string using dot as separator
var lastVal = arr.pop();       // Get last element
var firstVal = arr.join(".");  // Re-join the remaining substrings, using dot as separator

console.log(firstVal + " and " + lastVal);  //Printing result
```

Answer (score 11):

I will try something like bellow

```
var splitByLastDot = function(text) {
    var index = text.lastIndexOf('.');
    return [text.slice(0, index), text.slice(index + 1)]
}

console.log(splitByLastDot('123.2345.34'))
console.log(splitByLastDot('123,23.34.23'))
```

Answer (score 5):

I came up with this:

```js
var str = '123,23.34.23';
var result = str.replace(/\.([^.]+)$/, ':$1').split(':');
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result);
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

```
let returnFileIndex = str =>
    str.split('.').pop();
```

Comment: Could you please add an explanation for your answer? :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var str = '123.2345.34',
    arr = str.split('.'),
    output = arr.pop();
str = arr.join('.');
```

Comment: this will give "123.2345"

Comment: 123.2345 in `str` and 34 in `output`

Answer (score 1):

```
var test = 'filename.....png';
var lastStr = test.lastIndexOf(".");
var str = test.substring(lastStr + 1);
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm typically using this code and this works fine for me.

Jquery:

```
var afterDot = value.substr(value.lastIndexOf('_') + 1);
console.log(afterDot);
```

Javascript:

```
var myString = 'asd/f/df/xc/asd/test.jpg'
var parts    = myString.split('/');
var answer   = parts[parts.length - 1];
console.log(answer);
```

> Note: Replace quoted string to your own need

Comment: You realise that there isn’t any jQuery here, don’t you?

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution.
Simple Spilt logic

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

 var str = "123,23.34.23";
 var str_array = str.split(".");
 for (var i=0;i<str_array.length;i++)
 {
     if (i == (str_array.length-1))
     {
         alert(str_array[i]);
     }
 }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

My own version:

```
var mySplit;
var str1;
var str2;
$(function(){
  mySplit = function(myString){
    var lastPoint = myString.lastIndexOf(".");
    str1 = myString.substring(0, lastPoint);
    str2 = myString.substring(lastPoint + 1);
  }
  mySplit('123,23.34.23');
  console.log(str1);
  console.log(str2);
});
```

#### Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/no01uya0/

Answer (score 0):

```
Str = '123,23.34.23';

var a = Str.substring(0, Str.lastIndexOf(".")) //123,23.34 
var b = Str.substring(Str.lastIndexOf(".")) //23
```

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way is mentioned below, you will get **pdf** as the output:

`var str = "http://somedomain.com/dir/sd/test.pdf";
var ext = str.split('.')[str.split('.').length-1];`

> Output: pdf